# Mail from is not working properly (from email address is not appearing correctly)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have this code to send an email to the conference organizer:

```
   $user = Auth::user();
     $conference = Conference::find($id);
     $message = $request->message;
     $subject = $request->subject;
    Mail::to($conference->organizer_email)
    ->send(new UserNotification
    ($conference, $user, $message, $subject));
```

With this code the email is sent to the conference organizer, that is correct. The issue is that in the from address, instead of appear the email of the authenticted user, the user that sent the email, it appears the email configured in the .env file in the MAIL_USERNAME.

UserNotification:

```
class UserNotification extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $conference;
    public $user;
    public $message;
    public $subject;

    public function __construct(Conference $conference, User $user, $message, $subject)
    {
        $this->conference = $conference;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->subject = $subject;
    }
    public function build()
    {
         // shows the auth user email so why the received email is 
        // appears that was sent from the email
        // set in MAIL_USERNAME in .env file
        // instead of appear the auth user email?
        dd($this->user->email);

        return $this->from($this->user->email)->markdown('emails.userNotification', [
            'message' => $this->message,
            'subject' => $this->subject
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Laravel you on?

Comment: Its the version 5.5.

Comment: Are you using gmail as your smtp?

Comment: Yes, both the from email and to email are gmail emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass a sender email to gmail's smtp because will overwrite the headers to set the sender's email based on the configuration of your account.

You can update your account's configuration to add different sender: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en

Otherwise, you can create another gmail account specifically for your app.

```
appname@gmail.com
```

Or you will have to use another mail driver.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your UserNotification

```
class UserNotification extends Mailable
{
   use Queueable, SerializesModels;

   public $conference;
   public $user;
   public $message;
   public $subject;

   public function __construct(Conference $conference, User $user, $message, $subject)
   {
       $this->conference = $conference;
       $this->user = $user;
       $this->message = $message;
       $this->subject = $subject;
   }
   public function build()
   {
       return $this
            ->from($this->user->email)
            ->to($conference->organizer_email)
            ->markdown('emails.userNotification', [
               'message' => $this->message,
              'subject' => $this->subject
          ]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but same issue, the email address that appears in the from is also the email set in the .env file in "MAIL_USERNAME".

Comment: If "MAIL_USERNAME=" is empty then it appears an error sending email "Expected response code 250 but got code "530".

Comment: @John dd($conference->organizer_email); is not empty?

Comment: No, it appears the email of the conference organizer.

Comment: @John mail add to log? or send to real email?

Comment: Im not using log, the email is sent using gmail from an email to another.

Comment: @John in .end your MAIL_DRIVER, log? mailchip? sparkpost?

Comment: @John i think problem in your mail platform, need check can it send mails from different address

Comment: Its "    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
".

Comment: @John  I have done similar case with sparkpost, try,  they have free email.